# Status Bar Color - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-statusbar

How do I change the **Status Bar Color** of my app that I'm making in **Android Studio** so that it changes to a static color on Android Lollipop 5.0 or higher and doesn't crash on Mobile running lower version of Android OS.

Comment: Hey! I also posted a detailed ans.. feel free to check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, this works for me

```
//changing statusbar
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
                Window window = this.getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
            }
```

For changing color ActionBar :

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#ffff00</item>
    </style>
```

and declare on your manifest in application tag

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyActionBar" >
```

hope it help

Comment: in your activity you want to show statusbar color, just copy paste in method onCreate

Comment: Will this change the color automatically to match the action bar color or will I have to change a particular value to give it a color? (Sorry, I'm a beginner)

Comment: yes you must declare in color.xml  for example
`<color name="primary_dark">#3f41ac</color>`
you can change color match actionbar by changing that hexa

Comment: Thanks a lot... Now that you're here and answering, I'm gonna go with the flow and ask you one more question. How do I change the action bar color now? (I guess it's called action bar right?, the bar below status bar?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in 2 ways, either add attributes to your theme like

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">>#ED3B3B</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#BE2F2F</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#4DB6AC</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
</style>
```

and your AndroidManifest's application tag must have a theme attribute with AppTheme

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> // This
```

or if you wish to change status bar colour on a later stage dynamically, say on click of a button or after an image is done loading you can use inside your Java class

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.setStatusBarColor("your color"));
}
```

Comment: The app won't crash if it runs on Android version older than 5.0 right?

Comment: It won't. Just to add, as you are new. Try using `Toolbar` as well. You can replace the actionbar with toolbar and it gives you more control over your action bar.. https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Answer (score 0):

Please add this on your app style

```
<item name="colorPrimary">>#FFFF00</item>

<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
```